# How to get the variable value from android in the backend either HTML or javascript

Tags: javascript, android

I am creating an android application in which I want to read the value of array from android activity page so that I can use it in another web application. Please help me about how to get the value or what are the possible ways to retrieve values. 
Here is my activity code:

```
arrayPoints.add(new LatLng(arg0.latitude,arg0.longitude));
```

arrayPoints is the array. and it has the value of all the co-ordinates. How can I pass the value .

Comment: what you want to do? pass array to other activity or to web application?

Comment: I want to pass to web application

Comment: try webView.loadUrl('javascript: yourVariableInJavascript = " + yourVariableInAndroid + "');

Comment: In the activity page can I directly write this javascript loadurl.